# $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \{0,1\}$ be a function , does there exist an equilateral triangle in plane with vertices $x,y,z$ such that $f(x)=f(y)=f(z)$?

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \{0,1\}$ be a function ; then is it true that there exists an equilateral triangle in plane with vertices $x,y,z \in \mathbb R^2$  such that $f(x)=f(y)=f(z)$ ?

Comment: Why not the indicator function of the set of the vertices?

Comment: Don't you have also to assume the continuity of $f$ ?

Comment: @JoaquinSan : But that doesn't prove it for general any $f$ ... and by missing some hypothesis , what do you mean ?

Comment: @JeanMarie the images of $f$ are in $\{0,1\}$ ; if $f$ is continuous, it is constant

Comment: My mistake. I read that wrong. I'll think about it know.

Comment: @EmilioNovati : Indicator function of the set of vertices of what ?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at a point $x$, it's constant in $D(x, \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon$. Therefore we need to consider nowhere continuous functions.

Comment: You are missing something. If you want know if  $f(x)=f(y)=f(z)$ is true for **all** function than it is true for all **continuous** functions ( that are constant) but it is not true for all functions that are not continuous.

Comment: @EmilioNovati what's your  counterexample then?

Answer (score 4):

You can prove that there exists such a triangle using elementary considerations. Ad absurdum, let us suppose this is not.

[image]

Consider this hexagon. Suppose that $f(O)=0$. Among A,B,C,D,E,F, at least one has image $0$ (or we would have an equilateral triangle with equal images). We can suppose that $f(A)=0$. Then $f(B)=f(F)=1$.

But BFD is equilateral, so $f(D)=0$, and thus $fC)=f(E)=1$.

$f(O)=F(A)=F(D)=0$ and $f(B)=f(C)=f(E)=f(F)=0$.

Now consider a second hexagon with center A :

[image]

Using $f(B)=f(F)=1$, we have $f(T)=0$, so $f(U)=1$. But $UFC$ is equilateral and $f(U)=f(C)=f(F)=1$.